# How to automatically narrow the type in a `Record` typed object?

Tags: typescript

```
enum ResourceType {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
}

export type Resource = ResourceA | ResourceB

export type ResourceA = {
  type: ResourceType.A
  name: "A"
}

export type ResourceB = {
  type: ResourceType.B,
  name: "B"
}

const elements: Record<
  ResourceType,
  (resource: Resource) => void
> = {
  a: (resource: ResourceA) => (
    console.log(resource)
  ),
  b: (resource: ResourceB) => (
    console.log(resource)
  )
}
```

Typescript here says `Type '(resource: ResourceA) => void' is not assignable to type '(resource: Resource) => void'`.

That's expected.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically narrow the type based on the object key which should be matched with `resource.type`. I just can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @bugs answer, we do not really need a mapping since we already have the association stored in each `Resource` type. We can map over the `Resource` union to create your type.

```
type Elements = {
  [R in Resource as `${R["type"]}`]: (resource: R) => void
}

const elements: Elements = {
  a: (resource: ResourceA) => (
    console.log(resource)
  ),
  b: (resource: ResourceB) => (
    console.log(resource)
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=22&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA7CgG8AoKKAQSgF4oByAQ1oBpSoAhaugI2eIF9ixYAA9ciFABcoEvAThJUGTvOTpglAD6wEqjG0Eixk6bO0K1lGiTIz8ALjO6ssgHTlWIehGAOAROV9%20A1FxKVs5HUVgDitWcIcVKJx8FzYWMk9vPzZAgWJwqABRABtgbxAJeE5rKABtGCgASxBHKKh6KoADABJCGFrfcN8AXT5O4YcAChRItQSASmoAPigAN0RGgBMg4jREEHgpYFLyyocSstBK6tZ6KZnzDATZjHJFqhXJ1jI9g8RSlzFRAAc2mL2A81Y83SUC493Bz0e0Xen2%20UF%20SABQNBDyckLIkL4QA)

Comment: Thank you, that solves the stated issue.

Now building on that. Here is a weird error I get:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA7CgG8AoKKAQSgF4oByAQ1oBpSoAhaugI2eIF9ixAC54CcJKgydxydMEoAfWAlkY2gkfmUS5lGiTKbgALm2qsogHTlWIehBNQAROScsBw0WcnAO+1kamMj44+JZsLGR2DqZObG78Gl4AogA2wA4gQvCcBlAA2jBQAJYg3nJQ9DkABgAkhDD5TkZOALp81a2mABQoKj5BAJTUAHxQAG6IxQAmicRoiCDwQlDA6ZnZpmkZoNm5rPQ9fToYQf26w1Rj3axkC0uI6ZapiADmvecYltHAg6yDkSgXCOn0cwTkbEu11uUHuSCeL3ex3M33sv3+c2AAA9cIgUCs4StyEIhPQ0AALYDTcEYAAy9C4a04HxOYNBUKIrDWOyy8HyyJ8liMrRZ5j+fCAA

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud - yeah, this is known as *"correlated unions"* and there is an discussion about it here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581. I would say using `elements[resource.type](resource as any)` is not a "bad way" of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it.

Right now, you don't have a type that represents the mapping between resource types and resources, so we'll need to define it.

```js
type ResourceMapping = {
  [ResourceType.A]: ResourceA
  [ResourceType.B]: ResourceB
}
```

Then, you can use mapped types to specify the exact shape of your record.

```js
type ResourceRecord = {
  [R in ResourceType]: (r: ResourceMapping[R]) => void
}
```

Putting everything together, this is how it looks like

```js
enum ResourceType {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
}

export type ResourceA = {
  type: ResourceType.A
  name: "A"
}

export type ResourceB = {
  type: ResourceType.B,
  name: "B"
}

export type Resource = ResourceA | ResourceB

type ResourceMapping = {
  [ResourceType.A]: ResourceA
  [ResourceType.B]: ResourceB
}

type ResourceRecord = {
  [R in ResourceType]: (r: ResourceMapping[R]) => void
}

const elements: ResourceRecord = {
  a: (resource: ResourceA) => (
    console.log(resource)
  ),
  b: (resource: ResourceB) => (
    console.log(resource)
  )
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA7CgG8BYAKCigEEoBeKAcgEN6AaMigIVoYCNWyAvmTLAAHrkQoALlCl4CcJKgzU6JcrPkAuWAmTos8gHSV2UEIwjAdAIko3Bw0mInTN+XUoNc1Zufh1FfQwcfCMONg0LK1sOB1IhUhFxSRl-BT1lAjogrOoAH09g4A4ndKKsgFlGXFwASxAAc251CgBtXINQ4BMAXUDMg1MNDsGQ4w5+iu9HJNJyzow4NEkAExazDqgG6fH8KYAKFAGvDGrahsaO3oBKWgA+KAA3RDrV2bIVkHgZYAAbYBWEBSeAnYrLNYbDSMHRHMbWXbASh3GiPA5mChfJAAox-RCNOGnYA3Mw3SIUHiwlDwsFZDgotEYqBYxA4vEE6lEkkabkCIA)

---

This way, adding a new enum entry without doing anything else will result in a compilation error, forcing you to make sure that you have an appropriate mapping between the new entry and a new resource (you can try it out in the playground).

Similarly, specifying the wrong value for a given resource type will fail at compilation time.

```js
const wrongElements: ResourceRecord = {
   // Type '(resource: ResourceB) => void' is not assignable to type '(r: ResourceA) => void'.
  a: (resource: ResourceB) => (
    console.log(resource)
  ),
  b: (resource: ResourceB) => (
    console.log(resource)
  )
}
```